# Python Filtering two lists by values in one list

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, filter, zip

I am trying to filter a set of x,y coordinates by the value of the x-coordinate, such as in the following code:

```
x_list = [-4,-4,-3,-2,-2,-1,-1,1,2,3,4]
y_list = [0,2,-4,-2,4,-1,3,1,3,-1,4]

new_x = []
new_y = []

for i,x in enumerate(x_list):

    if x <= some_value:

        new_x.append(x_list[i])
        new_y.append(y_list[i])
```

Can this operation be performed more efficiently in one line with a lambda expression and functions like `map`,`filter`,`zip`?

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip like this:

```
for z in zip(x_list, y_list):
  print(z)
# prints tuples (x, y)
```

Or like this:

```
for x,y in zip(x_list, y_list):
  print(x)
  print(y)
```

All together:

```
points = [z for z in zip(x_list, y_list) if z[0] <= somevalue]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using zip, filter and lambda:

```
result = list(filter(lambda item: item[0] <= some_value, zip(x_list,y_list)))
```

You can do unzip the returned list of pairs of x_coordinate, y_coordinate:

```
new_x, new_y = list(zip(*result))
# new_x and new_y returned as tuple
```